# EC 2 free tier charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon AWS account, with a few EC2 running  instances (3) in different locations. I subscribed the 12 month trial. Suddenly, my billing dashboard started to stack up costs, updating every day.

The instances are virtual machines with windows server 2012, all configured  under the free tier settings. I use them mainly form testing, with few downloads/uploads and streaming.

They Are charging for a few bucks for data transfer,and also a reasonable amount described as EC2.

I've read somewhere  that one could create more than one EC2, and for what i supposed, the 750 hours limit is for each instance, But this probably is Wrong.

So, what can one do and not do, under the free Absolutely free tier limit ?

Comment: You get 750 hours a month of t2.micro instances in the free tier. If your total usage of your 3 instances is adding up to more than 750 hours a month, then you are going to be charged for the extra hours of usage. You should really take the time to read the documentation instead of just assuming what you heard from somebody meant that you could run unlimited free servers for a year.

Comment: Well, each time we are configuring a server, it says  free tier eligible. That's what i really hoped to be the case. Thanks

Comment: Yes they are each eligible. But your entire combined usage of all those servers has exceeded the free tier restrictions. You could run all three as long as you only ran each one 8 hours a day.

Comment: what about Traffic in/out ? are there any restrictions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html) you can run 750 hours of a Linux t2.micro or t1.micro instance plus 750 hours of a Windows t2.micro or t1.micro instance each month for the first 12 months under the free tier. So in your case you have exceeded the free tier limitations, by starting 3 Windows Server 2012 instances and keep them running more than 2/3 of the month.

Since AWS Free Tier involves 750hrs of Free Time per month, you could ideally start 750 EC2 instances, 1 hour/per month.

Comment: Starting 3 instances is not the problem, it is leaving all three running for more than 8 hours each, which exceeded the free tier limitations. You could run up to 24 servers under the free tier, as long as you only ran them 1 hour a day.

Comment: @MarkB Yes if he run 3 instances 2/3 of a month, it won't charge. But the case he has mentioned, relates to starting and running them more than 2/3 of a month which got him charged. I will update the answer to make it more meaningful. Thanks

Comment: what about Traffic in/out ? are there any restrictions ?

Comment: 15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services. More details on other limits check  https://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/?ft=n

Comment: @Ashan I'm not clear about 750 hours always free or only for the first 12 months? After the 12 months, we can be charged even if it not exceed 750 hrs?

Comment: @Sithu Yes. It is free for the first 12 months. After the first 12 months or exceeding the free tier limits you will be billed.